# Send email with info of stanza logs

Tags: python, logging, xmpp, sendmail

I am handling information from the stanza and one of the goals is to check if there is an error and send a notification via e-mail.

What I have been able to do is catch the error (either IqError or IqTimeout) and send a generic email with written information:

```
except IqTimeout:
  USERNAME = 'user'
  PASSWORD = 'password'
  sender = 'someguy@myemail.com'
  receivers = 'bshell@myemail.com'
  message = """From: SomeGuy <someguy@myemail.com>
        To: Barbara Shell <bshell@myemail.com>
        Subject: Alert of an Error

        This is a test e-mail message: IqTimeout
        """
        smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.sendmail.net', 123)
        smtpObj.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
        smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
        print "Successfully sent email"
```

I also tryed to print the log with the information from the 'error' stanza, but only got one field:

```
logging.error("Could not register account. Error code: %s" %e.iq['error']['code'])
```

What I want is the information of error form my stanza to be send to an email, that basically can go with something like this:

```
To: bshell@myemail.com
From: someguy@myemail.com
Subject: Alert of an Error

This is your error: 

RECV: <iq to="bshell@myemail.net/36457242971338462713453506"    from="chat.test.net" id="3" type="error"><oo xmlns="http://chat.net/profile" /><error code="404" type="cancel"><remote-server-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas" /></error></iq>
```

I am writting in python. If you need any more info, I'll be more than willing to answer!

Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Comment: What XMPP library are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include the received error stanza in your email, you need only do:

```
except IqError as e:
    ...
    message = """...

    RECV: %s""" % e.iq
```

If you want to extract only portions of the error data, you can use any of:

```
e.iq['error']['code']
e.iq['error']['type']
e.iq['error']['condition']
e.iq['error']['text']
```

which, in your example would respectively provide:

```
'404'
'cancel'
'remote-server-not-found'
"" # Because no human friendly text was included
```

Now, here is what may be the issue you're facing. When you catch the `IqError` exception, `e.iq` is the response stanza which includes the error data which can be accessed as in the above. If you are catching `IqTimeout`, then `e.iq` is the *original* stanza which never received a response. In that case, there really is no error XML to extract data from. Of course, you may still get what looks like error data, but that would be due to the fact that an error element is inserted when accessing `e.iq['error']` if one does not already exist.

Don't forget that there is the `sleek@conference.jabber.org` room for SleekXMPP related help.

-- Lance

Comment: thanks Lance! now how can I enter the sleek@conference.jabber.org? new on this!

Comment: If using adium, then File > Join Group Chat, and then enter sleek as the room name, and conference.jabber.org as the server. Most clients operate in a similar way.